# Breakpoints in XCode debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging

I don't understand what's going on with the XCode debugger. I am using Xcode 3.1.2 and GCC 4.0 on 10.5.  Sometimes,   Occasionally, I test a C++ program,  all active breakpoints become disabled.  No breakpoints are taken - the program runs to completion.  The dark blue breakpoint icons change to light blue or yellow with a blue border.   Looking at the breakpoints list (CMD-Opt-B ) after the change, the breakpoints that were tagged with a checkmark are now tagged with a hyphen. (how do I get a "checkmark" icon with markdown?)

This is after they have been functioning normally.  Sometime later, they will usually begin functioning normally again.  I don't know what is responsible for either change.   I have closed/reopened the debugger, files, and the full project.  Most often, the proper beakpoint status is restored when I trivially change a source file and do a "Build & Debug" (Cmd-Y), but that doesn't always fix things

I have  seen the reports of problems about "GLIBCXX_DEBUG_" here and elsewhere.  That isn't my problem because I am using GCC 4.0, and don't use those flags.  I have also seen reports of a similar problem with a really old XCode.  Again, I don't believe that applies to me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When the breakpoint markers turn yellow it means that you have more than one program being actively debugged by GDB. Try exiting all the programs except for the one you are currently debugging.

Comment: I believe the change in  color must mean something else besides "more than one".  I just logged out, and then started XCode immediately after logging in.  I then made a breakpoint with a dark blue icon.  Upon starting the program with either a "Build & Debug" (CMD-Y) or "Debug" (CMD-OPT-Y), the breakpoint icon turns yellow w/blue border, and the program runs to completion.

Answer (score 0):

A yellow breakpoint symbol indicates the breakpoint is not loaded into the debugger. This can happen if you have more than one project running is what the previous answer was implying. Can also go yellow if you Run with breakpoints off instead of on.

Comment: As noted, I did a "fresh" launch of XCode (only one project), and breakpoints were initially enabled.  At this point, I think I stumbled on some combination of factors that manifest as a bug.